# PHP Notice - Custom Function

Tags: debug

I am using this code:

```
function the_alt_title($title= '') {
    $page = get_page_by_title($title);
    if ($p = get_post_meta($page->ID, "_x_entry_alternate_index_title", true)) {
        $title = $p;
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter('the_title', 'the_alt_title', 10, 1);
```

In debug.log i get

```
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/my-child/functions.php on this line:

 if ($p = get_post_meta($page->ID, "_x_entry_alternate_index_title", true)) {
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: You need to do a check on $page to make sure it has the property of 'ID'

Comment: Looking at the source code of [`get_page_by_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_title/#source), you'll notice it will return nothing if the page was not found, so go `if ( !empty($page->ID) && $p = get_post_meta($page->ID, "_x_entry_alternate_index_title", true) )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$page = get_page_by_title($title)` - this line is failing somewhere, so you should do a check on this to make sure it exists.

Like so:

```
function the_alt_title($title= '') {
    $page = get_page_by_title($title);
    if (!$page) {
        return $title;
    }

    if ($p = get_post_meta($page->ID, "_x_entry_alternate_index_title", true)) {
        $title = $p;
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter('the_title', 'the_alt_title', 10, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have to globalize page to access it.

```
    function the_alt_title($title= '') {
    global $page; //here
    $page = get_page_by_title($title);
    if ($p = get_post_meta($page->ID, "_x_entry_alternate_index_title", true)) {
        $title = $p;
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter('the_title', 'the_alt_title', 10, 1);
```